# How do I make an ArrayField using MongoEngine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

There isn't an ArrayField option in mongoengine's documentation. Here it is: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html
I'm going crazy over how something like that isn't named ArrayField. Is it even possible to do an ArrayField using mongoengine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `ListField` in mongoengine.

More details here:
http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ListField

e.g.

```
from mongoengine import Document

from mongoengine.fields import ListField
from mongoengine.fields import StringField

class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    roles = ListField(StringField()) # something like ["ro", "rw"]
```